# My node running ropsten testnet has blocknumberlower than blocknumber on ropsten.etherscan.io

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten

It returned `false` in rpc console after typing `eth.syncing`, and eth.blockNumber returned `11243029` while the latest block on ropsten.etherscan.io is 11258008, about 15000 blocks behind!
Where's the problem?

My init command

```
geth --ropsten --syncmode "snap" --cache=1024 --http --http.api "eth,net,web3,personal,admin" --http.addr <my http addr> --http.port <my port> --maxpeers "32" --allow-insecure-unlock
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
It turns out that ropsten has a erroneous split in early September, since then if you use "snap/fast" mode, you'll be hooked to a wrong chain.

relevant link here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/posgnx/psa_ropsten_testnet_has_a_large_erroneous_split/